# Cloudera Manager failed to format HDFS, topology.py.vm is missing

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I encountered an error while adding a new service (Service Type = HDFS) using Cloudera Manager (Free Edition). The error message says as follows:

> Could not create process: com.cloudera.cmf.service.config.ConfigFileSpec$GenerateException: Unable to process template:**couldn't find the template hadoop/topology.py.vm**

I checked /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log and found a line like below.

> org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: **Unable to find resource '/WEB-INF/templates/hadoop/topology.py.vm'**

I guess that a certain war file does not contain hadoop-metrics.properties.vm (Velocity template file?) although it should do and that this might be related to [WHIRR-370](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WHIRR-370).

Could you help me to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask which version of Cloudera Manager is being used? Does this error occurred just after you try to add add the service of after some time when the service is added?

Based on the error, it seems some of the configuration is missing that why service addition failed. So I would like to know how did you install Hadoop on this cluster?

If you download the virtual machine and compare from your installation, you can compare the folder for completeness and missing content. It does work for me always.

Comment: Engineers of Cloudera Japan kindly pointed me out a possibility that Cloudera Manager (3.7.6) had been installed incompletely for some reasons. So, following their advice, I uninstalled Cloudera Manager and tried the setup from the beginning again. In my case, I could get a successful result by that. Anyway, thank you for giving me an experienced advice!

Comment: I believed the same that your installation was incomplete. Grateful if you accept the posting as answer which I indicated correctly.